# Facebook login WebView orientation is wrong on iOS 8

Tags: ios, facebook, webview, ios8, popupwindow

When I use `WebView` to make user login our game on iOS8 (use the  `FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView` ), I find the orientation is not correct. 
I check the code everywhere but still don't know why. The login popup box is works fine on iOS7. I don't find where the code I can set the orientation or size of the Facebook WebView. Did anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: I open WebView like this :  [FBSession.activeSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:
                 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
                 {
                     OpenSessionCallback(session, status, error);
                 }];

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to the latest Facebook SDK (version 3.20) fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook fixed this issue with in version v3.18 released on September 3, 2014

FacebookSDK.framework

**Fixed:**

Bolts.framework is now installed in the FacebookSDK directory
* Fixed the orientation of web dialogs when linking against the iOS 8 SDK

Just update to the latest version of Facebook SDK.